# Показать объект в обозревателе объектов

Tags: hotkeys, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Есть ли в студии горячая клавиша или иной способ, чтобы открыть выделенный объект в обозревателе объектов?

Как `F12` но вместо редактора кода должен открываться object browser.

Answer (score 1):

Смотри здесь: [Visual Studio 2010 Keybinding Posters](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13189).

Comment: Про object browser там только `Clrt + W + J` -- открывает вкладку с ним. Выделенный объект не учитывается.